# How to color a diff quoted by Mutt in Vim?

Tags: vim, colors, diff

What is the best way to color diff, quoted in Mutt, using Vim?

If I receive a diff as attachment, I want to comment some lines, but while replying mutt adds the quotation mark (`>`) which is fine for me, but then it breaks the diff coloration in Vim.

How to add to the current diff pattern to match even with the first `>` chars? (It would be better to match more `^[> ]` patterns)

Example of diff quoted message:

```
> @@ -52,22 +48,17 @@
> -msgid "foo is deprecated."
> +msgid "bar is deprecated."
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by writing a custom syntax file, say ~/.vim/syntax/muttdiff.vim:

```
syn match quote "^>* "
syn match quotedDeletion "^>* *-.*" contains=quote
syn match quotedAddition "^>* *+.*" contains=quote

hi quotedDeletion ctermfg=red
hi quotedAddition ctermfg=green
hi quote ctermfg=white
```

And make vim source the file if it is editing a mutt message.

It's a good start if you want to learn how to create a custom syntax file for vim.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the **indent_string** from it's default value ("> ") to an empty string using a **macro**. 
Example with a key "**,r**" bound:

```
macro index ,r ":set indent_string=\"\"<enter><reply>"
```

You would need to set it back to default after the  command. So something like:

```
macro index ,r ":set indent_string=\"\"<enter><reply>:set indent_string=\"> \"<enter>"
```

(Take care those are not tested - just guessing the syntax here.)

But there is another issue - vim usually opens in the fileformat set to "mail" or something like that. You would need to set it to "diff" explicitely. So in Vim you need to:

```
:set filetype=diff
:syntax on
```

Maybe another macro or something like that. I know this is not ideal, but it's something at least ;-) Good luck.